# Transition to transparent: gradient following a curved selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, transparency, gradient, photo-editing

Take a look of the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I'd like to soft the transition between the left image and the background (red colour on the example to simplify the question).

On Photoshop, I have tried to apply gradient masks to a handmade selection and using the erase tool. The results are not good.

I'm running out of ideas. Maybe Photoshop is not good for that, and I should try Illustrator instead?

Comment: seems you're editing a photo, I'd say Photoshop is a better tool than Illustrator for that.

Comment: Could you show us your attempts, and tell why your are not content with the results? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Illustrator:

Add an Opacity Mask. It can be done in the Transparency Panel. You must have the red in the background. Draw a shape that covers the transition area. Fill it with BW gradient. My shape is only a coarse polygon.

[image]

Deselect option "clip", it causes global transparency outside the mask area

[image]

As already commented, use rather Photoshop if your worksheet has no vector art. You will save your nerves. There You can add a layer mask (=generally white, BW gradient on the selected area) and behind all must be a red layer.

[image]

For a good result the mask must be fine tuned manually by extremely soft brush.